# How to use GROUP BY after the Having clause Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, join, group-by

Here is the query which gets the accounts for a specific user the products are related to accounts in `one-to-many` relation so for each product there are four permissions

All the accounts which is not `Disable` and also shows their permissions 
I got all accounts according to scenario but the problem is if one account has more than one products then it obviously shows account id more than one time

**What i am looking for to `GROUP BY` the `a.id` after the `HAVING` clause which checks the permissions ** but no luck getting syntax error

```
Error Code: 1064 right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY a.`id` LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 14
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT  a.`id` AS aid,ap.`pid`, p.`products_name`, a.accounts_account_number, c.clients_name,a.accounts_product_type AS pptype,
c.`clients_last_name`, a.`accounts_account_name`
,(SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Readonly' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Readonly,
(SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Buy' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Buy,
(SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Sell' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Sell,
(SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Disable' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS `Disable`
 FROM `bf_clients` c INNER JOIN `bf_user_clients` uc ON (c.`id` = uc.`client_id`)
 INNER JOIN `bf_accounts` a ON (c.`id` = a.`accounts_clients`)
 INNER JOIN `bf_account_products` ap ON (a.`id` = ap.`aid`)
 INNER JOIN `bf_products` p ON (ap.`pid` = p.`id`)
 WHERE uc.`agt_user_id`=2 AND a.deleted=0 AND c.deleted=0                
 HAVING (Readonly !='' OR Buy !=''  OR Sell !=''  OR `Disable` !='' ) 
 AND `Disable` !='1'   ORDER BY a.`id`  GROUP BY a.`id`
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use an outer select

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM
(
  SELECT a.`id` AS aid,ap.`pid`, p.`products_name`, a.accounts_account_number, c.clients_name,a.accounts_product_type AS pptype,
         c.`clients_last_name`, a.`accounts_account_name`,
         (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Readonly' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Readonly,
         (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Buy' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Buy,
         (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Sell' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Sell,
         (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Disable' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS `Disable`
    FROM `bf_clients` c INNER JOIN `bf_user_clients` uc ON (c.`id` = uc.`client_id`)
   INNER JOIN `bf_accounts` a ON (c.`id` = a.`accounts_clients`)
   INNER JOIN `bf_account_products` ap ON (a.`id` = ap.`aid`)
   INNER JOIN `bf_products` p ON (ap.`pid` = p.`id`)
   WHERE uc.`agt_user_id`=2 AND a.deleted=0 AND c.deleted=0                
  HAVING (Readonly !='' OR Buy !=''  OR Sell !=''  OR `Disable` !='' ) AND `Disable` !='1'   
) q
 GROUP BY aid
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the `GROUP BY` to between the `WHERE` and the `HAVING`.

```
SELECT  
    a.`id` AS aid, 
    ap.`pid`, 
    p.`products_name`, 
    a.accounts_account_number, 
    c.clients_name, 
    a.accounts_product_type AS pptype, 
    c.`clients_last_name`, 
    a.`accounts_account_name`,
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Readonly' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Readonly,
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Buy' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Buy,
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Sell' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS Sell,
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Disable' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) AS `Disable`
FROM `bf_clients` c 
    INNER JOIN `bf_user_clients` uc ON (c.`id` = uc.`client_id`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_accounts` a ON (c.`id` = a.`accounts_clients`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_account_products` ap ON (a.`id` = ap.`aid`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_products` p ON (ap.`pid` = p.`id`)
WHERE uc.`agt_user_id`=2 AND a.deleted=0 AND c.deleted=0                
GROUP BY a.`id`
HAVING (Readonly !='' OR Buy !=''  OR Sell !=''  OR `Disable` !='' ) 
    AND `Disable` !='1'   
ORDER BY a.`id`
```

Also, move anything that needs to be checked **BEFORE** the `GROUP BY`, into the `WHERE`

Since you are using the `HAVING` to filter on an aliased subquery, you have should either (option A) add the whole subqueries into the where clause **OR** (option B?) why don't you just join the table used in the subquery?

*Option A Example `WHERE` clause:*

```
WHERE uc.`agt_user_id`=2 AND a.deleted=0 AND c.deleted=0 
    AND (
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Readonly' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) != '' OR 
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Sell' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`) != '' OR 
        (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Disable' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`)  != ''
        )
    and (SELECT `status` FROM `bf_account_permissions` WHERE `permission`='Disable' AND uid=2 AND aid=a.id AND pid=ap.`pid`)  != '1'
GROUP BY a.`id`
-- REMOVED THE HAVING
ORDER BY a.`id`
```

*Option B Revised with a `LEFT JOIN`:*

**NOTE:** *This option below has just been roughly put together without any tables / data, so may need some adjustment.  Further suggestion to improve this are welcome!*

```
SELECT  
    a.`id` AS aid, 
    ap.`pid`, 
    p.`products_name`, 
    a.accounts_account_number, 
    c.clients_name, 
    a.accounts_product_type AS pptype, 
    c.`clients_last_name`, 
    a.`accounts_account_name`,
    case when perms.`permission` = 'Readonly' then perms.status end as ReadOnly, 
    case when perms.`permission` = 'Buy' then perms.status end as Buy, 
    case when perms.`permission` = 'Sell' then perms.status end as Sell, 
    case when perms.`permission` = 'Disable' then perms.status end as `Disable`
FROM `bf_clients` c 
    INNER JOIN `bf_user_clients` uc ON (c.`id` = uc.`client_id`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_accounts` a ON (c.`id` = a.`accounts_clients`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_account_products` ap ON (a.`id` = ap.`aid`)
    INNER JOIN `bf_products` p ON (ap.`pid` = p.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `bf_account_permissions` perms on (a.id = perms.id) 
        and (perms.pid = ap.`pid`)
        and (perms.uid=2)
WHERE uc.`agt_user_id`=2 AND a.deleted=0 AND c.deleted=0
    and (perms.status !='' or (perms.`permission` = 'Disable' and perms.status !='1'))
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY a.`id`
```

Comment: No i want `GROUP BY` the `a.id` after the HAVING clause

Comment: @dianuj That would be incorrect syntax.  Read my edit.  If there is anything you want to check BEFORE the `GROUP BY`, you must move it into the `WHERE`

Comment: How do i check the conditions of `alias`  with  `where` clause

Comment: @dianuj I have updated with 2 options to do this

Comment: You option A works fine but it is taking to much time while running subqueries twice its complicated and option 2 is empty if you check the answer of peterm its perfect and taking the original time as before my query was taking 
But many many thanks for your help and +1 for you